# Setting font size in ActiveReports Excel is very slow

Tags: excel, activereports

I am exporting massive amounts of data to an excel sheet. We are running into performance issues with trying to properly format the data for a report in Active Reports. I set up some basic print outs to determine what sections of code are taking the longest parts of time. I broke apart the cell formatting with setting the cells value.

```
Private Sub SetSheetFormat(intRow As Integer, dDSheet As DDSheet)
    Dim startRow As Integer = 6
    Dim cells As Cells.DDCells = dDSheet.Cells(dDSheet.Cell(startRow, 0), dDSheet.Cell(intRow, 45))
    cells.FontSize = 8
    dDSheet.Cell(intRow, 47).SetValue((Date.Now - start).ToString())
    cells = dDSheet.Cells(dDSheet.Cell(startRow, ReportColumns.FirmDemands), dDSheet.Cell(intRow, ReportColumns.SI_SSDollars))
    cells.Alignment = Style.HorzAlignments.Right
    dDSheet.Cell(intRow, 48).SetValue((Date.Now - start).ToString())
    cells = dDSheet.Cells(dDSheet.Cell(startRow, ReportColumns.FirmDemands), dDSheet.Cell(intRow, ReportColumns.NetFcst))
    cells.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 224, 192) 'light orange
    dDSheet.Cell(intRow, 49).SetValue((Date.Now - start).ToString())
    cells = dDSheet.Cells(dDSheet.Cell(startRow, ReportColumns.FirmTfrsOut), dDSheet.Cell(intRow, ReportColumns.KitComptUsage))
    cells.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 192) 'light yellow
    cells = dDSheet.Cells(dDSheet.Cell(startRow, ReportColumns.FirmProd), dDSheet.Cell(intRow, ReportColumns.PlannedTfrsIn))
    cells.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(&HC0FFC0) 'light green
    cells = dDSheet.Cells(dDSheet.Cell(startRow, ReportColumns.TotalReceipts), dDSheet.Cell(intRow, ReportColumns.TotalReceipts))
    cells.FillColor = Color.FromArgb(&H80FF80) 'dark green
    dDSheet.Cell(intRow, 50).SetValue((Date.Now - start).ToString())
```

With approximately 7000 rows in the spreadsheet. The time it took to write the data before it entered this method was 6 seconds. Setting the fontsize to 8 took 50 seconds alone. Is there a better way of doing this? I thought applying it to multiple cells at once would do more of transactional thing and be more efficient but it is not.

UPDATE:
Please note that we are not generating this workbook from a PageReport or PageDocument. We are writing what we want directly to a Workbook.

Comment: are you referring to the activereports product from grapecity?   which version are you using?   I do not recognize ReportColumns??

Comment: @GrapeCity Team Yes from GrapeCity. The reportcolumns is an enum we used to keep track of a column name to a column number. We are using version 10.

Comment: @GrapeCityTeam Do you know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [SpreadBuilder](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#arWLKBasicSpreadsheetWithSpreadBuilder.html) to export the data to Excel file. In [SpreadBuilder](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#arWLKBasicSpreadsheetWithSpreadBuilder.html), data is exported cell by cell in the Excel file and since you have massive amounts of data, it took so much time to export the data. Then to modify the data, again it has to traverse each cell and then format the cell so it took 50 seconds. Basically, the issue is caused because the amount of data is very large and [SpreadBuilder](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#arWLKBasicSpreadsheetWithSpreadBuilder.html) works cell by cell for Excel export.

Better way can be, you can make the modification on the fields of the report while generating the report or before you want to export and then export using [Export filters](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#Excel.html)/[Rendering Extensions](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/index.html#RenderingtoExcel.html). This is the only way to optimize Excel export in this scenario.

Comment: We were originally making the modifications as we were writing the data to each cell. It took just as long. I can check into writing the data to a PageReport vs SpreadBuilder but I'm sure there some things unique to SpreadBuilder that we needed when we first wrote the code. This is also all done in memory before we even save the Workbook to a file.

Comment: Yes, you can check with writing data to a PageReport and try to accomplish the requirements by making modifications while creating the report. You can share your observations if you face any issue. Regarding the SpreadBuilder, I would like to inform you that it will take some time as it works cell by cell and data is huge in your case. It is the intended behavior.

Comment: Looking into PageReport it appears that this will basically require an entire rewrite of our report engine. Unless there is some documentation I'm missing, we can't just generate and design a report in code. That is all data binding and using a report generator prior to runtime. I think we are going to pursue some open source solutions at this time.